# How to find the /dev name of my USB device

Tags: linux, mount

I am running a Ubuntu 11 guest on a Windows XP host with VMware. I want to format an SD card in Ubuntu, but I can't figure out which `/dev/xxx` device the SD card is.

I plug the card into the built-in socket of my laptop. I "safely remove" the device in Windows. Then, I "connect" the PCMCIA reader in VMware. Now, I was supposed to see a new device like `/dev/sdx`, but it doesn't appear.

How can I find what the name of my USB device's name and mount it?

`/var/log/message` is empty.

Here is the output of dmesg:

> `[ 5268.927308] usb 2-1: new full speed USB device number 12 using uhci_hcd`

And, here are the last lines of `/var/log/syslog`:

> `Oct 31 18:51:21 ubuntu kernel: [ 5268.927308] usb 2-1: new full speed USB device number 12 using uhci_hcd`
>
> `Oct 31 18:51:21 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-1"`
>
> `Oct 31 18:51:21 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 12 was not an MTP device`

Comment: Ubuntu 11 does not have /var/log/messages...

Comment: This should be on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/) or [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 87):

Try `lsblk`. This is the output from my current setup:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 195.3G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 266.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 460.8G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: For Mac users:          >> diskutil list

Answer (score 35):

```
ls -1 /dev > ~/before.txt
```

plug it in, then

```
ls -1 /dev > ~/after.txt

diff ~/before.txt ~/after.txt
```

Comment: Like a true programmer solution. +1

Answer (score 8):

`lsblk` seems to work:

```
rishi@rishi-Inspiron-1018:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 230.9G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   7.4G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   7.4G  0 part /media/3765-3233
```

So now I know my SD card is in `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: Suspect. When using Debian live, I saw sdc (my usb device) listed in lsblk output but not in /dev.

Comment: It'll appear in /dev only if udev is present (or an equivalent), and as a rule to create the node in it. Does not mean it can't be used, you can create the node where you want, since you have the Major/Minor number in lsblk.

Answer (score 5):

Using `lsblk` with some custom output columns I was able to find a more precise solution. See:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,MAJ:MIN,RM,SIZE,RO,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT,VENDOR,HOTPLUG
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT                     VENDOR   HOTPLUG
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk                                ATA            0
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi                                     0
└─sda2   8:2    0 223.1G  0 part /                                             0
sdb      8:16   1 238.3G  0 disk                                SanDisk        1
└─sdb1   8:17   1 238.3G  0 part /media/my-host/AAAA-BBBB                      1
sdc      8:32   1  59.5G  0 disk                                SanDisk        1
└─sdc1   8:33   1  59.5G  0 part /media/my-host/AAAA-BBBB                      1
```

Using `lsblk -h` it's possible to see all available output columns, and I added the `VENDOR` and `HOTPLUG` columns.

Looking at my output it's easy to see that I have 2 `HOTPLUG` devices (usb devices in my case) from `SanDisk`

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

If it has a label use `/dev/disk/by-label/[USB label]` to format the disk

EDIT:
Try `/dev/disk/by-id/usb*`

Comment: no, it doesn't have :(

Comment: aren't there any other methods?

Comment: USBs are usually /dev/sb followed by a number, or something along thoses lines if I'm not completely correct, it might be /dev/sdb followed by a number but not normally /dev/sda, so if there's only one plugged in that should do it

Answer (score 3):

Try using `lsusb` to see if the sd card reader is picked up in virtualbox. Another option would be to use `palimpsest` (also known by its menu entry, **Disk Utility**.)

Don't be afraid to use the GUI programs - they do work! If palimpsest sees your device, it will tell you the device node, so you can use the CLI utilities.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo fdisk -l` will list the partition table on all available hard disks; it uses the Linux naming scheme for disks, handy for troubleshooting and remembering which partition is where.

Use `man fdisk` for more information on the parameters of `fdisk`.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and run `ls /dev` before you enable that USB device in vmware. Run `ls /dev/` again after you enabled it and look for what pops up

Comment: this is the most painful way of doing it, not to mention, many devices have numerous instances in /dev/ once they get initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`bootiso` utility](https://github.com/jsamr/bootiso), which has a flag to do exactly that:

```
> bootiso -l
Listing USB drives available in your system:
NAME                HOTPLUG   SIZE STATE   TYPE
sdd                       1  14,7G running disk
sde                       1   961M running disk
```

To install it:

```
curl -L https://rawgit.com/jsamr/bootiso/latest/bootiso -O
chmod +x bootiso
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# dir /dev/disk/by-path/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 180 Aug 26 15:51 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 120 Aug 25 17:20 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Aug 25 17:12 pci-0000:00:03.2-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Aug 26 15:51 pci-0000:00:03.2-usb-0:4.1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 26 15:51 pci-0000:00:03.2-usb-0:4.1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 26 15:51 pci-0000:00:03.2-usb-0:4.1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 26 15:51 pci-0000:00:03.2-usb-0:4.1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part3 -> ../../sdb3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Aug 25 17:12 pci-0000:07:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 25 17:12 pci-0000:07:00.0-scsi-0:2:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
```

and

```
# dir /dev/disk/by-id/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 280 Aug 27 01:20 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 120 Aug 25 17:20 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 25 17:20 dm-name-VG_RAID_201010081812-LV_RAID_201010081617 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 27 01:20 dm-name-top4 -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 25 17:20 dm-uuid-LVM-XCQXKaPB3snmEgx9ZNGRssIxGmJPje6TXKMLyop5meKH3x3KiJ1H1q3aoqgXpci1 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Aug 25 17:12 scsi-36842b2b04963f900144207e1091bf90c -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 25 17:12 scsi-36842b2b04963f900144207e1091bf90c-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Aug 25 17:12 usb-ASUS_SBW-06D2X-U_3248433031354B4A30303030-0:0 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Aug 26 15:51 usb-ST916041_2AS_579FFFFFFFFF-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 26 15:51 usb-ST916041_2AS_579FFFFFFFFF-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 26 15:51 usb-ST916041_2AS_579FFFFFFFFF-0:0-part2 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 26 15:51 usb-ST916041_2AS_579FFFFFFFFF-0:0-part3 -> ../../sdb3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Aug 25 17:12 wwn-0x6842b2b04963f900144207e1091bf90c -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Aug 25 17:12 wwn-0x6842b2b04963f900144207e1091bf90c-part1 -> ../../sda1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to linux, but so far I have found 3 ways to find out a device name:

1) `lsblk` (already mentioned above, lists device names and the folder they are mounted on)

2) `sudo fdisk -l` (lists device names, here you can also see the names of partitions)

3) `dmesg` immediately after you have inserted an usb stick (a lot of output, don't really know yet what they are for, but the last entries show the name of the inserted name somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

It is important to differentiate between two scenarios:

1. The USB stick is plugged in, and recognized and accessible in the file browser, then it got automatically mounted;
2. After the device was plugged in and got mounted, you have ejected/unmounted the device, and now it is safe to unplug.

In the first case, using `lsblk` will list all the mounted devices. Under the `MOUNTPOINT` column you should see your USB device listed being mounted somewhere under `/run/media/`.

In the second case (after you have ejected the device), even though `lsblk` **will not list anything**, the dev file should be still the same as when it was mounted. You can verify it is still there with `lsblk --all`. But as it is unmounted now, the `MOUNTPOINT` column will be empty.

For example, suppose you want to `dd` an iso image to a USB stick. First plug in the stick, then look with `lsblk` for the associated dev file (based on the `MOUNTPOINT`), then unmount/eject the mounted device and use `dd if=stuff.iso of=/dev/sdX` to write your image. These steps are important, as it is not a good idea to [overwrite a mounted device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794213/what-happens-when-i-use-dd-to-overwrite-the-disk-from-which-ubuntu-is-running).

Answer (score 0):

For types like me, I strongly suggest adding:

status=progress

to dd's list of arguments, so you can see it's working

Comment: This has no effect or value to finding the /dev name of a device.